# Pasar valor de variable INT a otra clase en Java

Tags: java

Estoy usando Eclipse y JFrame para crear un programa. Necesito pasar el valor de una variable tipo INT de una clase a otra, pero, cuando intento hacerlo, el valor de la variable dentro del `frame` de la segunda clase es `0`.

class Padre:

```
public class PAdre extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Global
     */
    private int id_pelicula = 2;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Padre() {
        setTitle("Clase Padre");
        setBounds(100, 100, 628, 410);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        btnVerReferencias = new JButton("Ver Ref.");
        btnVerReferencias.setEnabled(false);
        btnVerReferencias.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                claseHijo classHijo = new claseHijo ();
        // Paso el valor de la variable
                classHijo.setIdPelicula(id_pelicula);
                classHijo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnVerReferencias.setBounds(12, 288, 110, 74);
        contentPane.add(btnVerReferencias);

    }
}
```

class Hijo:

```
public class classHijo extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Global
     */
    private int id_pelicula;

  // Recibo el valor de la variable
    public void setIdPelicula(int id_pelicula) {
        this.id_pelicula = id_pelicula;
        }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public classHijo () {
        setTitle("Clase Hijo");
        setBounds(100, 100, 628, 410);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);    

    // Le asigno el valor de la variable global
        int otraVariableINT = id_pelicula;
        System.out.println("otraVariableINT : " + otraVariableINT);
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
otraVariableINT: 0
```

Por qué la variable `id_pelicula` vale `0` dentro del `frame` de la clase Hijo?. Se supone que esta variable es global y mantiene su valor en toda la ejecución del programa no?.

Cuál es la forma correcta de pasar un valor a otra clase y que esté disponible para usar dentro del `frame`, qué hago mal?.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68751/discussion-on-question-by-robert-gomez-pasar-valor-de-variable-int-a-otra-clase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas cometiendo el mismo error de la vez pasada. Recuerda que el **constructor** es el primer método en llamarse de un **objeto**. Eso es algo obvio porque cuando declaras la instancia de una clase, lo que estas haciendo es llamando al constructor.

```
claseHijo classHijo = new claseHijo ();
```

`new claseHijo()` es la instancia del objeto, que es tambien el constructor de la clase `claseHijo`. Ten eso en mente, cuando creas una instancia, estas llamando el constructor de esa clase.

Ahora bien, si te fijas bien, en el constructor estas imprimiendo el valor de la variable `id_pelicula`; el cual es cero (cero es el valor por defecto de las variables de tipo `int`) porque a la variable `id_pelicula` le pasas el valor cuando llamas el método `setIdPelicula()`, que se ejecuta después del constructor. Quizás me preguntes. Se puede llamar ese método antes que el constructor? No, no hay manera, el constructor siempre es el primer método que se llama de un objeto.

Sabiendo esto hay dos soluciones:

1. Has lo que vallas a hacer con la variable `id_pelicula` (ya sea imprimirla, asignarla a otra variable... lo que sea) dentro del método `setIdPelicula()`.

   ```
   public void setIdPelicula(int id_pelicula) {

       this.id_pelicula = id_pelicula;

       // Le asigno el valor de la variable global
       int otraVariableINT = id_pelicula;

       System.out.println("otraVariableINT : " + otraVariableINT);

   }
   ```
2. Pasa el valor de la variable `id_pelicula` en el constructor de la clase.

   ```
   public classHijo (int id_pelicula) {

       this.id_pelicula = id_pelicula;

       setTitle("Clase Hijo");
       setBounds(100, 100, 628, 410); 
       JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();   
       setContentPane(contentPane); 

       // Le asigno el valor de la variable global 
       int otraVariableINT = id_pelicula;
       System.out.println("otraVariableINT : " + otraVariableINT); 
   }
   ```

---

#### Otras correcciones

Los nombres de las clases tienen que iniciar con mayuscula. No es solo por convención, eso ayuda a diferenciar las clases de los objetos y las variables.

classHijo ❌
ClassHijo ✅

Comment: Gracias amigo mío, ahora veo cuál es mi error, siempre confundo esas cosas al pasar datos de un lugar a otro. Todo funciona bien con tus consejos.

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser que tu variable global **id_pelicula** en  tu clase **Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas** está inicializada en 0 y según veo tus prints en el stacktrace lo primero que haces en el flujo de tu aplicación es llamar al método **actualizarReferencias()** y posteriormente seteas el valor a **id_pelicula**. Es por eso estas tratando de obtener un valor que no está seteado en tu variable global de hecho incluso tratas de obtener el valor antes de que este se ejecute el método de la clase padre que envía el valor

***EDITADA***

Observando tus clases me doy cuenta que no tienes claro como hacer el flujo de una aplicación, primero que nada tu aplicación no tiene por que tener varios puntos de inicio, es decir solo tendrías que tener un solo main en todo el proyecto y no un main por cada clase. ¿Cuál es la clase que ejecutas para iniciar la aplicación?

Ahora tu método **actualizarReferencias(int id_pelicula)** de la clase 
 **Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas** como te mencioné es el primero que se llama. Sin embargo este se está llamando después de del método **actualizarReferencias(id_pelicula)**

El gran problema es que está llamando al método **actualizarReferencias(id_pelicula)** desde el constructor de la misma clase y lo peor es que está leyendo una variable global **id_pelicula** y se lé pasa como parámetro al método **actualizarReferencias(id_pelicula)** lo cual no tiene ningún sentido ya que la variable es global

Te lo ejemplifico, tienes la variable global  **id_pelicula**  al no estar inicializada toma como valor 0 luego cuando tu clase se ejecuta debes de saber que lo primero que se ejecuta es el constructor. el cual pasa el 0 de la variable **id_pelicula** al llamar al método **actualizarReferencias(id_pelicula)** pero no necesitas pasarlo ya que es global.

La verdad pudiera seguir todo el día dándote a conocer todos los errores o malas prácticas que haces a la hora de programar pero ese no es el objetivo.

Asi que primero que nada corrige toda tu aplicación solo dejando un solo main, si el flujo comienza por la clase **Vista_pelicula**  puedes setear la variable **id_pelicula** pasando el parámetro por constructor en vez de por método.

```
            Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas vistaVerReferenciasPeliculas = new Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas(id_pelicula);
```

y en tu clase **Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas** declara que tu constructor reciba un argumento, lo setee y no pases el parámetro al llamar a **actualizarReferencias** ya que es global y el método tiene acceso a el

```
   public Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas(id_pelicula){
      this.id_pelicula = id_pelicula;
      ...
      ...
      actualizarReferencias();
    }
```

Eso te solucionará el problema por el que abriste el tema aunque realmente no es un problema, ya que no es necesario llamar a **vistaVerReferenciasPeliculas.setIdPelicula(id_pelicula)**

Y por último si quieres mejorar, investiga el patrón DTO  porque es una mala practica tener variables globales, que si estás utilizando multihilo no sé por que no sabes usar dicho patrón.

***EDICIÓN 2***

La verdad llevo muchos años sin utilizar las librerías swing de java sin embargo estoy completamente seguro que no necesitas un main por clase o por frame si lo único que quieres es que se carguen todas tus ventanas cuando ejecutes tu clase principal **Vista_pelicula** lo único que debes hacer es crear la instancia hacia todos lo frames que necesitas cargar y ponerlos como visibles

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Vista_pelicula frame = new Vista_pelicula();
                frame.setVisible(true);

               //Desde aquí llama a todos tus frames que necesites
                   Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas frame = new 
                            Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Pero si aun así quieres conservar todos tus main y tu código tal como está necesitarás utilizar 2 patrones de diseño un DTO y un singleton.

Comment: Entiendo, cómo puedo solucionarlo, podrías editar tu respuesta con una posible solución?, te lo agradecería, estoy perdido.

Comment: Tu código no se puede ver en codeshar, por lo que para que yo o alguien mas te ayude necesitarías colocar tu código de ambas clases en el tema (al menos debe contener el contenido completo de los metos) y agregar desde donde se esta llamando  al método actualizarReferencias(). Por otro lado sin ver nada de código lo único que te podría decir es que antes de  llamar a actualizarReferencias() crea una instancia de la clase padre y con ella llama al método que contiene la primera parte del código que pusiste (si el codigo no esta dentro de un metodo metelo en uno).

Comment: Hola Polo, al parecer el otro usuario ha borrado todo el código de codeshare. He editado mi post inicial y he agregado todo el código que necesitas. Espero puedas ayudarme.

Comment: Hola. Mi código está de esa manera porque estoy haciendo un programa en Eclipse con WindowsBuilder, o sea, JFrame y cada JFrame tiene un main() por defecto, no puedo eliminarlos. He intentado antes el metodo que indicas, pero, lanza error ya que el constructor original del JFrame no recibe parametros y esto no puede modificarse. No puedo tocar el constructor original del JFrame ya que a partir de aqui es que la clase se carga y aparece la ventana en pantalla con todos mis componentes. Por esta razon, debe de haber otra manera de pasar algo de una clase a otra de forma facil, alguna idea?

Comment: Hola, entiendo tu observacion, hago lo mismo, pero, dentro de cada boton para abrir determinada ventana. Bueno, investigare mas sobre las tecnicas que indicas. Volviendo al tema, sigo teniendo el problema sobre pasar el INT a la otra clase, no logro hacerlo, no puedo hacerlo por constructor como indicas. Habra alguna forma de pasarlo via un metodo o algo?, es lo que estaba haciendo pero no me funciona. Espero puedas ayudarme, es solo pasar un simple INT. No puede ser por constructor si usas JFrame como es mi caso.

Comment: Una de las característica principales de POO es sobrecarga, ello conlleva a que puedas tener los constructores que necesites (siempre y cuando esperen diferentes parametros) si no puedes borrar el constructor principal, solo crea otro contructor con que reciba el parametro y ahi metes el codigo que no esta relacionado al frame otra opcion es simplemente sacar borrar  la linea que llama a actualizarReferencias() y colocala en la clase Vista_pelicula justo despues de setear la id  coloca esto vistaVerReferenciasPeliculas.actualizarReferencias();

Comment: Hola, he probado tu solución, pero, tampoco me funciona. Yo llamo a actualizarReferencias dentro del frame y por ende me lanza error, no le estoy pasando ningun argumento. Debo tener el INT por otra vía, ya sea un método global o algo, pero no se cómo porque lo que he intentado me da error.

Answer (score 0):

Tu variable **id_pelicula** de la clase **Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas** vale 0 porque no la inicializaste con ningún valor, como es un primitivo **int** el valor por defecto es **0**.

Sin embargo creo que la confusión acá viene ya que debés pensar que como en la clase **Vista_pelicula** al atributo id_pelicula le asignaste un valor de **2** entonces en la clase **Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas** que también tiene un atributo con el mismo nombre también debería tener asignado ése valor, por lo cual no es así.

**A tener en cuenta:**

Decidiste extender las dos clases de **JFrame** por ende la Clase **Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas** ya no la podrías extender de **Vista_pelicula** para heredar el atributo id_pelicula, ***y aún así, si la extendieras el valor de la variable va a ser distinto entre clase y clase***, porque en verdad aunque se llamen igual son variables diferentes en clases distintas que pueden tener diferentes valores entre padres e hijos.

```
import logicas.Logica_verReferenciasPeliculas;

public class Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas extends JFrame {

/**
 * Global
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTable table;
private int id_pelicula;
Logica_verReferenciasPeliculas logicaVerReferenciasPeliculas  = new Logica_verReferenciasPeliculas();

 // Recibo el valor de la variable
public void setIdPelicula(int id_pelicula) {

//Creas un objeto Vista_pelicula para poder acceder a su atributo id_pelicula.
    Vista_pelicula v = new Vista_pelicula();

//Le asignas al id_pelicula de esta clase el id_pelicula que viene de la clase Vita_pelicula. Tecnicamente deberia funcionar. este método getId_pelicula() lo inventé asumo que como tenés privado el atributo seguramente lo tengas declarado no se si asi pero bueno.
    this.id_pelicula = v.getId_pelicula();
    }

// Recibo el INT como parámetro
void actualizarReferencias(int id_pelicula) {
    try {
        DefaultTableModel model = logicaVerReferenciasPeliculas.tableReferencias(id_pelicula); // Uso el INT
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception:\n" + e, "Error: actualizarReferencias()", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
}

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas frame = new Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Vista_verReferenciasPeliculas() {
    setTitle("Referencias");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 628, 410);
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

// Llamo a la función y le paso como argumento un número INT
    actualizarReferencias(id_pelicula);
}
}
```

Comment: Hola, la observación que indicas es cierta y de hecho, lo sé y lo tengo claro, pero, mi problema no era ese, al menos no es la duda que tenía. De igual forma no has respondido con una solución al problema, mi duda sigue. Sé que las variables se llaman iguales en ambas clases, lo hice a propósito. Mi problema es cómo le paso el valor de la variable a la otra clase, he intentado muchas formas y nada me funciona.